# pyassimp.load extremely slow or hanging indefinitely

Tags: python, 3d, fbx, assimp

I am trying to load a low-poly FBX file into my python program with pyassimp, but it is unusable slow. I am using pyassimp version 4.1.4, and I built assimp version 5.2.5 from source (https://github.com/assimp/assimp/releases/tag/v5.2.5, vs2022, release config, x64).

I have an FBX file that is about 2MB in size, has 2332 triangles, 32 bones and 17 animations. I am trying to import it with pyassimp, but pyassimp.load seems to hang indefinitely (> several minutes)

Here is my code:

```
import os

os.environ["PATH"] += ";C:\\Software\\assimp-5.2.5\\bin\\Release"
print("\n".join(os.environ["PATH"].split(";")))

import pyassimp as simp


def fbx_load_routine(modelObject, path):
    print("Loading fbx: " + os.path.realpath(path))
    scene = simp.load(path)
    print("Done.")
    assert len(scene.meshes) == 1

    mesh = scene.meshes[0]

    print(mesh)

    print(dir(mesh))

    simp.release(scene)

    return modelObject


class ModelAsset:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def load_fbx(self, path):
        # Process(target=fbx_load_routine, args=(self, path)).start()
        fbx_load_routine(self, path)
        return self

    @classmethod
    def from_fbx(cls, path):
        return ModelAsset().load_fbx(path)
```

in another script, I call `ModelAsset.from_fbx(...)`

I am using the following python version:
"Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
", and am running the code inside pycharm.

Comment: That sounds strange to me. Could you open an issue report on https://github.com/assimp/assimp with the simple model, please?

Comment: Sure, I will do that today.

Comment: @KimKulling I'm getting unpredictable behavior (hanging, crashes, etc.) with other low-poly fbx models. I think I will look into it more before posting an issue. You can close this question.